# Retrieving and showing a saved image (documents folder) in a UI Image View

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an app in which the user selects a profile photo. It is saved in the documents directory as NSData. I am having trouble finding code that will allow me to now retrieve it and show it in the UI Image View. Any help would be appreciated.

```
let image = UIImagePickerController()
image.delegate = self
image.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
image.allowsEditing = false

self.present(image, animated: true) {
}

@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        profileImageView.image = image

        let imageData: NSData = image.pngData()! as NSData
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsPath = paths[0] //Get the docs directory
        let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).appendingPathComponent("userprofilephoto.png").absoluteString //Add the file name
        imageData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true) //Write the file

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        //error message
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.size.height / 2.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the saved image like this:

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
if let dirPath = paths.first {
   let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("userprofilephoto.png")
   let retrieved_img  = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)

   // retrieved_img is your UIImage
}
```